# How do I use CNTK Trainer function without eval (just loss criteria)?

Tags: cntk

I normally call trainer with criteria that includes both loss and evaluation criteria, e.g.,

my_trainer = Trainer(out, (loss, label_error), [learner])

However, when I tried to call it with loss (without evaluation criteria):

my_trainer = Trainer(out, loss, [learner])

I got an error:

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Is there a way to train without defining evaluation criteria?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
my_trainer = Trainer(out, (loss, None),[learner])
```

If you checkout the GAN tutorial, it will have an example.

https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tutorials/CNTK_206_Basic_GAN.ipynb